# Buscador en una tabla javascript

Tags: javascript, tablas

tengo una tabla que me muestra lo que tengo en la clase Paciente. Quiero añadirle un buscador arriba para filtrar datos, pero no sé como hacerlo.

Esta es mi clase:

```
    //clase PACIENTE
class Paciente extends Persona {
    constructor(sDNI, sNombre, sApellidos, sDireccion, sCorreo, iTelefono, iEdad, fAltura, sObjetivo,fPeso) {
        super(sDNI, sNombre, sApellidos, sDireccion, sCorreo, iTelefono);
        this.edad = parseInt(iEdad);
        this.altura = parseFloat(fAltura);
        this.Objetivo = sObjetivo;
        this.peso = parseFloat(fPeso);
    }
    toHTMLrow() {
        let linea = document.createElement("tr");
        let celda = linea.insertCell(-1);
        celda.textContent = this.dni;
        celda = linea.insertCell(-1);
        celda.textContent = this.nombre;
        celda = linea.insertCell(-1);
        celda.textContent = this.apellidos;
        celda = linea.insertCell(-1);
        celda.textContent = this.direccion;
        celda = linea.insertCell(-1);
        celda.textContent = this.correo;
        celda = linea.insertCell(-1);
        celda.textContent = this.telefono;
        celda = linea.insertCell(-1);
        celda.textContent = this.edad;
        celda = linea.insertCell(-1);
        celda.textContent = this.altura;
        celda = linea.insertCell(-1);
        celda.textContent = this.Objetivo;
        celda = linea.insertCell(-1);
        celda.textContent = this.peso;
        return linea;
    }
}
```

Y de esta manera lo inserto en una capa que tengo en el index

```
Nutrilife.prototype.listadoPaciente = function () {

    let tabla = document.getElementById("tabla");
    let cabecera = tabla.createTHead();
    let fila = cabecera.insertRow(-1);
    let celda = fila.insertCell(-1);
    celda.textContent = "DNI";
    celda = fila.insertCell(-1);
    celda.textContent = "Nombre";
    celda = fila.insertCell(-1);
    celda.textContent = "Apellidos";
    celda = fila.insertCell(-1);
    celda.textContent = "Direccion";
    celda = fila.insertCell(-1);
    celda.textContent = "Email";
    celda = fila.insertCell(-1);
    celda.textContent = "Teléfono";
    celda = fila.insertCell(-1);
    celda.textContent = "Edad";
    celda = fila.insertCell(-1);
    celda.textContent = "Altra";
    celda = fila.insertCell(-1);
    celda.textContent = "Objetivo";
    celda = fila.insertCell(-1);
    celda.textContent = "Peso";
    let cuerpo = document.createElement("tbody");

    for (var i = 0; i < this.tPacientes.length; i++) {
        cuerpo.append(this.tPacientes[i].toHTMLrow());
    }
    return cuerpo;
}
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?
Necesito hacer un listado con filtros, pero por más vueltas que le doy e intento no sé si de esta manera sería posible.

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Por qué no usas una biblioteca como DataTables?

Comment: Esta quizás no sea la respuesta que buscas conseguir pero trabajar tablas en vanila te tomara mucho tiempo te recomiendo usar footable [Footable](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/)